# Recurrence Equation for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, recurrence

I'm pretty new to recurrence equation concepts, need help with following algorithm

```
G(n)
Require: A positive integer n.
if n <= 1 then
return n
else
return 5*g(n - 1) - 6* g(n- 2)
end if
```

I came up with following recurrence equation for above :

> T(n) = n, if n<=1, 
>  
>   T(n) = 5*T(n-1) - 6.T(n-2),  if n>1

Is this correct, I also have to setup a recurrence for the number of multiplications performed by this algorithm. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence relation that you have built here is correct. Its basically you writing a problem in form of some smaller sub-problem.

Now for the number of multiplications. Keep 2 things in mind.

1. Number of steps you need to go down in the recurrence relation to reach the base case (n<=1 in this case).
2. Number of operation in each case.

Now for your recurrence.

> T(n) = n, if n<=1
>
> T(n) = 5*T(n-1) - 6.T(n-2), if n>1

You have a recursion that changes a problem to two sub problems at each step and at each step the value of n decreases by 1

T (n) = 5*T(n-1) - 6*T(n-2)
T (n-1) = 5*T(n-2) - 6*T(n-3)

So n steps each time branching into 2 sub problems so you will have 
2 * 2 * ... 2 (O(n) time)
So there are 2^n steps in your problem approximately hence O(2^n)
And each step has 2 multiplication and one subtraction.

A recurrence for number of multiplications will be like this

> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 2

So the number of multiplication will be approximately  ( 2^n )*2.